# Parse files to merge them into a global docx file (in PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following snipper that creates a docx file (coming from https://github.com/krustnic/DocxMerge)

```
 $dm->merge( [
'file1.docx', 'file2.docx'
], "vendor/templates2/result.docx" );
```

My goal is to parse into a folder, get all the files and use them instead of writing manually 'file1.docx', 'file2.docx' and so on.

I made that :

```
$myarray = glob("vendor/templates/*");
usort($myarray, create_function('$a,$b', 'return filemtime($a) - filemtime($b);'));

foreach($myarray as $key => $value)
{
  $result .= "'". $value. "'". ",";
  }

$result2 = substr($result, 0, -1);
//echo $result2;

 $dm->merge( [
$result2
], "vendor/templates2/result.docx" );
```

But that does not work.. The error message is the one :

> No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/citeos/vendor/krustnic/docx-merge/src/DocxMerge.php on
>   line 30

The line corresponding to the error is this one :

```
if ( !copy( $docxFilesArray[0], $outDocxFilePath ) ) {
// Cannot create file
return -2;
```

How could I do to make my docx file with all the files coming from my foreach loop ?
Thanks you very much !

Comment: Maybe use absolute instead of relativ pathes here.

Comment: Why are you doing strings with `' '`, an not make a real array `$result[]=$nextfile`? Currently `[$result2]` will not work, because you are not creating an array with values. You are creating an array with one value that looks like `["'asd','sadsad'"]`?!?

Comment: So do `$result[] = $value;` and `$dm->merge( $result, "vendor/templates2/result.docx" );`, if that work tell me and i make answer from it.

Comment: My bad... Thank you very very much. Didn't realized that was the thing to do but now it's perfecly clear !